# Is there a way to plot multivariate multiple linear regression results?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, linear

I run a Multivariate Multiple Linear Regression with 5 predictors (X1..X5) and 5 dependent variables (Y1..Y5) by using SPSS. I was wandering which is (if there is) the best way to plot the contributes of the significant predictors for each Y by using ggplot / pandas / spss. I thouhgt to simply plot the β values using histograms but by doing so the direction of the relationship between X's and Y's will get lost. Anyone have any suggestion? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe arrange the 5 X variables on the horizontal axis from "generally most important" to "generally least important" (perhaps use average absolute stdized beta for this.) Then plot the five standardized betas above the corresponding X variables for one particular DV. Connect with lines to show that they are all together. Now overlay the standardized betas for the remaining 4 DV s in the same way, using different plot symbols and connecting line types. Finally, add a legend indicating which plot symbols and line types belong to which DV s. Hopefully it is not too much of a mess.

Comment: Correction: plot the *absolute* (or perhaps squared) standardized betas.

Comment: Or maybe use side-by-side bar charts, with a different color for each DV, arranged essentially as described above in my previous comments, in five groups of five each.